# summing across rows, leaving NAs in R

Tags: r

In R, I would like to sum across rows but keep NA's as NA if the whole row is NA. My data contains 0's and I want to count them as such. E.g.:

```
colA  colB  colC  Total
 1     NA   2       3
 NA    NA   NA     NA
 0     NA   NA      0
 3     0    NA      3
```

I used the code below and got 0's for the all-NA rows. If I change na.rm to F, I get all NAs all the way down. I would like get NA in the all-NA rows.

```
Total <- as.data.frame(rowSums(df[,1:3], na.rm = T))
```

Thanks!

Comment: @demongolem: please don't reject edits from the OP which add a reproducible example;  they are not "intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this to get total and then `cbind` it with your dataframe .

```
apply(df,1,function(x){if (sum(is.na(x)) == length(x)){
    return(NA)
}else{
    sum(x,na.rm = T)
}
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply change the results in a second pass:

```
dat <- data.frame(colA=c(1,NA,0,3),  colB=c(NA,NA,NA,0),  colC=c(2,NA,NA,NA))
 dat
  colA colB colC
1    1   NA    2
2   NA   NA   NA
3    0   NA   NA
4    3    0   NA
 res <- rowSums(dat,na.rm=T)
 res
[1] 3 0 0 3
 res[rowSums(is.na(dat))==3] <- NA
 res
[1]  3 NA  0  3
 dat <- data.frame(colA=c(1,NA,0,3),  colB=c(NA,NA,NA,0),  colC=c(2,NA,NA,NA))
 dat
  colA colB colC
1    1   NA    2
2   NA   NA   NA
3    0   NA   NA
4    3    0   NA
 res <- rowSums(dat,na.rm=T)
 res
[1] 3 0 0 3
 res[rowSums(is.na(dat))==3] <- NA
 res
[1]  3 NA  0  3
```

And if you want save it back in your data:

```
df$total <- res
```

Comment: I would like to keep 0 as it is a meaningful value in my data set so I don't want all-NA rows to zero out. see edited/corrected post.

Comment: I don't quite get where you're going...  Seems to me my solution work also with you're updated data.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one line using a manipulation of NA.

```
rowSums(df, na.rm=TRUE) * NA^(rowSums(is.na(df)) == length(df))
[1]  3 NA  0  3
```

Here, the first `rowSums` gets the sums while removing NAs. This is then multiplied by `NA^(rowSums(is.na(df)) == length(df))`, which returns NA in all cases except when the exponentiated term is 0 (or FALSE). In this case, FALSE occurs when at least one element of the row is non-NA.

Comment: Thanks for a diff approach

Answer (score 1):

In two steps like the above answer (but shorter):

```
sums <- rowSums(df, na.rm=TRUE)
allna <- apply(df,1, function(x)all(is.na(x)))
sums[allna] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Dplyr (in one step);

```
t1<- data.frame ( A=c(1,NA,0,3),
              B=c(NA,5,NA,0),
              C=c(2,NA,NA,NA))
t1<-t1 %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Total=sum(A,B,C,na.rm=T))
```